# Would it be weird if I use the word "prevailing" in this context?

Tags: meaning

Mud flat is prevailing in the country

Is it weird to use "prevailing" to say there are many mud flat places ??

Comment: Hi @Sam Probably better phrased as, 'mudflat**s** **prevail** in the country'

Comment: I would say "Mud flats are **prevalent** in the country."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevailing is an adjective and as such would normally be used in conjunction with a noun, so to use it in the way you intend, you would probably be best to say:

> The prevailing terrain in the country is mud-flats.

The use of the noun "terrain" gives "prevailing" something to qualify and makes more sense, so yes, your initial sentence would seem a little weird.